# can't run 32 bit dll in python 32 bit on 64 bit platform

Tags: python, c, dll, 32bit-64bit

**short summary:**
I have a DLL that detects hooks in the computer (it's a version I found on the internet) and it's working on 32-bit so I figured I should also use the 32-bit version of Python.
Now, my OS is 64-bit but I read other problems and they said it shouldn't be a problem as long as the process that is running it (Python) is in 32-bit.
so I ran the program and it said:

> '''This program does not currently support 64-bit hosts. Failed to
>   attach to desktop 'Default'.'''
>
> '''FATAL: c:\users\1\downloads\hookd1\hookdll\desktop.c line 781, 
>   init_global_desktop_store(): add_all_desktops() failed. Couldn't add
>   any desktops.'''

Which means 64 bit machine can't run it but as you can see in the code below it is just a warning and should work (I think):

```
void warn_x64( void )
{
    USHORT x64_host = 0;


    /* IsWow64Process() is not always available. alternative:
    Windows x86 host GS register is 0, x64 GS register is not
    */
#if defined( _MSC_VER )
    __asm
    {
        mov x64_host, gs
    }
#else
    asm( "mov %%gs, %0" : "=r" (x64_host) );
#endif

    if( x64_host )
        MSG_WARNING( "This program does not currently support 64-bit hosts." );

    return;
}
```

**my attempts to fix the problem:**

- changing python to the 32-bit version
- running the DLL in `sysWOw64` using `regsvr32` (didn't quite understand the solution but the DLL seems to not work unless I'm missing something).
- changed my Visual Studio project from debug version to release because dependency check said it uses `msvcr100d.dll` which I didn't have so I changed the DLL to release version.
- Another solution I tried and didn't work:
  A fix I saw somewhere was to change from `Any CPU` to `x86` in the solution, but my solution has only 2 other options which are 'active(win32)' and `win32`.
  Mine currently sits on `active(win32)` and I think it's the one that should support and for those who are saying I should try win32 as well, I rebuilt the solution with `win32` and it gave the same problem.

**brief final explanation of what I want:**
I've read similar questions to mine and tried their solutions but none of them fixed my problem, all I want is to run my 32-bit DLL in Python 32-bit although my os is 64-bit (the C program said it doesn't accept 64 hosts but it should according to other solutions pointed in stackoverflow, it is also just a warning).
conclusion: 
I excepted it to run in this 64-bit environment (because the DLL runner, Python, is in 32-bit).
but instead, it didn't run because the program seems to warn about 64 hosts.

**EDIT**:
I should also mention the source [code](https://github.com/jay/gethooks). Although I made changes to the output the DLL gives is different, but I didn't change anything else except for the output.

Thanks to anyone who tries to help me fix this very annoying problem!